# Are there any large aquatic mammals in Zootopia?

Tags: zootopia

Zootopia makes an effort to include mammals at almost every scale from every possible environment. There's Tundratown, Sahara Square, the Jungle place, home to animals from artic shrews to elephants. However, I didn't see any large aquatic mammals. Are there dolphins or whales that I missed? If there aren't, has the production team publicly discussed why there aren't any?

Comment: Don't worry, they will be in the direct to home video Birdtopia and Aquatopia, when Judy and Nicks hybrid baby gets exiled for being unnatural.

Comment: Not every animal had to have evolved. Maybe the tree-hugging iguana liked being a tree-hugging iguana.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the artbook ["Art of Zootopia](https://youtu.be/b4awFMpUbZk?t=2m54s)", it was simply too difficult for the film's concept artists to work out how to include large aquatic creatures (and other non-mammal animals) in the city. So they were just gently *airbrushed* out of the picture.

> *The team spoke with zoologists, animal behavior specialists, and
>   scientists who study animal evolution. Based on what they discovered,
>   the filmmakers decided to limit the film’s animals to mammals,
>   although “reptiles and birds and other animals do exist on this
>   planet. We just don’t go to those continents,” says screenwriter and
>   co-director Jared Bush. This constraint led to an “aha!” moment that
>   became a central tenet of Zootopia—that mammals are divided into two
>   groups: predators and prey, and prey animals outnumber predators
>   ten-to-one.*

Answer (score 2):

[image: Hippo Subway]

They show hippos, which are large aquatic mammals.  Further we see that the hippo commuters use a special water-filled "subway" that presumably could be used by other aquatic mammals.

Answer (score 1):

I believe zootopia is like a regular zoo. If you go to a regular zoo, you can see lions, elephants, apes, birds, etc... , you don't see whales or dolphins only in an Aquazoo/park which Zootopia isn't.
If you look at the [Zootopia Disney Wiki](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Zootopia) you can see the cast here and all the animals that are in the movie:

- Ginnifer Goodwin as Judy Hopps, a rabbit
- Jason Bateman as Nick Wilde, a red fox
- Idris Elba as Chief Bogo, a cape buffalo
- Jenny Slate as Bellwether, a sheep
- J. K. Simmons as Mayor Lionheart, an African lion
- Nate Torrence as Clawhauser, a cheetah
- Shakira as Gazelle, a gazelle
- Bonnie Hunt as Bonnie Hopps, a rabbit
- Don Lake as Stu Hopps, a rabbit
- Tommy "Tiny" Lister as Finnick, a fennec fox
- Alan Tudyk as Duke Weaselton, a weasel
- Maurice LaMarche as Mr. Big, an arctic shrew
- Phil Johnston as Gideon Grey, a red fox
- Raymond S. Persi as Flash, a three-toed sloth
- Tommy Chong as Yax, a yak
- Octavia Spencer as Mrs. Otterton, an otter
- Jesse Corti as Manchas, a black jaguar
- Katie Lowes as Dr. Badger, a honey badger
- John DiMaggio as Jerry Jumbeaux Jr., an African elephant
- Peter Mansbridge as Peter Moosebridge, a moose
- Mark "Rhino" Smith as Officer McHorn, a rhinoceros
- Kristen Bell as Priscilla, a three-toed sloth
- Leah Latham as Fru Fru, an arctic shrew
- John Lavelle as Mouse Foreman
- Rich Moore as Doug, a ram
- Byron Howard as Bucky Oryx-Antlerson, a kudu, and Travis, Gideon Grey's weasel friend.
- Jared Bush as Pronk Oryx-Antlerson, an oryx
- Josh Dallas as Frantic Pig Gita Reddy as Nangi, an elephant
- Fuschia as Drill Sergeant, a polar bear
- Zach King as a wolf

Comment: Actually, Zootopia isn't like a regular zoo. There aren't any apes or monkeys, reptiles or birds. Thanks for the Wiki content though!

Comment: Um... Every zoo I've been to has aquatic animals... At the very least they have fish and turtles. My home zoo even has bigger mammals like seals/sea lions. I'm not really certain what this list does for your answer, though. The question is asking whether aquatic mammals exist, not for a list of all the speaking characters. There are tons of mammals in the film that aren't speaking roles but are seen, including gerbils, mice and other small mammals, so the list isn't even complete.

Comment: @Catija I believe that totally depends where you are. I live in Belgium and in our zoo's there aren't any aquatic creatures. It's split.